# ionic 5 "Notifications are not allowed" with xcode 12.4

Tags: angular, xcode, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

After updating to Xcode 12.4, the Firebase Push Notifications stop working, giving me the message "**Notifications are not allowed for this application**".
I updated all Ionic, Angular and Capacitor packages to the latest, did some Apple certificates again, it always return this message it gets to "**PushNotifications.requestPermission()**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, my App's name was in Portuguese and had an acute accent, with the new version of Xcode I think they removed this option.

I could keep the name of the app with acute accent, but i had to change the "**Product Name**" to another one.

You can change that in your xcode project

App.xcodeproj -> Targets -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> **Product Name**